# How to solve sync between Alert closing and document.readyState

Tags: selenium

I have the following general VB code:

* Test code: Call Selenium SetKeys and populate several fields on a web form.

* Test code: Then call SetKeys on an Html input element with an OnChange event.

* Selenium inserts the value into the text box.

* The OnChange event fires calling a Javascript function.

* The JS function displays Alert or Confirm dialog.

* Test code: Get text from dialog:

DialogText = DriverObj.SwitchTo().Alert().Text

* Test code: Close dialog

    DriverObj.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept()

()
* Then eventually I call Executescript with: "return document.readyState"

I get: OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException: 'Modal dialog present'

I'm running the VB in debug mode. So I see this happen:

1) Test code starts IE.

    IE displayed as top window.

2) Test code fills in web form.

3) Test code fills in textbox with OnChange event.

4) Code stops at breakpoint.

    Visual Studio now displayed as top window.

    IE displayed in background.

5) DriverObj.SwitchTo().Alert().Text successfully gets the dialog box text.

6) DriverObj.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept() successfully runs.

7) Code gets to ExecuteScript "return document.readyState".

8) IE window is displayed in front of VS window.

9) Dialog is displayed in IE.

10) Code executes ExecuteScript "return document.readyState".

11) Code displays exception: OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException: 'Modal dialog present'.

I've tried calling DriverObj.SwitchTo().Alert() after dismissing it with Accept() to ensure the dialog has disappeared but I still get the 'Modal dialog present' exception.

What can I do to ensure IE has completely finished displaying and closing then dialog box before I call 'return document.readyState'?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you can try:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
// Wait until alert is NOT present
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()));
// OR Wait until number of windows is 1 i.e. main content
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(1));
```